# Video player is not working.. in Ububtu 14.04

Tags: video, video-player

While opening the Video player it showing as

[Install Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gut07.png)

Then trying to install the plugin it showing as..

[Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PrGJ.png)

Comment: Your sources.list is corrupted... follow the solution and keep your internet on and do it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type

```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't help then do this

```
  sudo apt autoremove <packagename>
```

If this doesn't help then you
Need an internet connection.Type in terminal

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install your video player plugins :)